# Connect Windows printer to Linux machine via samba

Tags: linux, samba, windows, printing

How can I connect my Windows printer to a Linux (RHEL5) box via samba? I'm looking for a clear configuration file

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to configure CUPS. Open the CUPS web interface at https://localhost:631 and click on "Add Printer" (don't be scared if it takes a while, it's scanning the network for network printers). If it does not automatically list your printer you can choose "Windows Printer via SAMBA". As URL enter:

smb://[workgroup/]server[:port]/printer  (workgroup and port are optional).

Next you just chose the right model and the printer should work.

Comment: Pls give me configuration of samba for printer ! Am i want to create a smb account for printer ?

Comment: When i use administration tab, i ask user name and password, What's it ?

Comment: On Ubuntu (and probably other sudo-oriented distributions) it's your user name and password. On other systems it's the root account.

Comment: And no, you need no samba account for the printer. Cups talks to the Windows host, the samba configuration is only relevant if you want to export your printers on Linux to other systems.

Comment: thanks by your guidance i did it successfully. I got clear idea about cups.

Comment: Also had to install "samba-client" package